# Super le déguisement Why is there a le in this phrase?

Tags: grammaire, sens, vocabulaire, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique

This means "great disguise", and the specific person that was being referred to by this phrase was wearing a costume.

Why do i need the le is it because of specificity or it is an idiom?

Answer (score 3):

On utilise "le" dans ce cas seulement:

- à l'oral jamais à l'écrit
- et quand la phrase comporte une suite implicite que l'on ne mentionne pas

Exemple:

- Super le déguisement [que tu portes]
- Super le resto [que tu as choisi]
- Jolie la robe [que tu portes]

Mais par contre / sinon on dirait:

- Super déguisement / Super ce déguisement
- Super ce resto / Super resto
- Jolie cette robe / Jolie robe

Answer (score 2):

*Super le déguisement* doesn't exactly mean "great disguise".

It would be better to write it with a comma and an exclamation mark:

> *Super, le déguisement !*

That means:

> *(Il est) super, le déguisement !* (It is) great, the disguise!

Answer (score 0):

Il me semble ici que 'le' sert à mettre l'accent sur l'objet de la réaction produite, le déguisement.
'Super déguisement' se dit aussi, mais me semble comporter un 'degré' d'emphase moindre.

e.g. in english :

- "Great disguise !"
  versus
- "What a great disguise !"